# event that fires when returning from second view controller

Tags: ios, swift

Is there an event that fires in parent controller when returning from second view controller?  The purpose would be to refresh some data (view) in the parent controller.  The equivalent in Android would be onResume

Comment: What is second view controller and how did you navigate to it? Did you use a segue? Post some code perhaps

Comment: You can use `protocol`. Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24299231/3734028) for more

Comment: It is s straight view controller to another view controller with a normal segue.  Nothing special.  Will look up the protocol route but it seems like a complex solution for a very basic issue.

Comment: @MicheleDiblasi Or you can also refresh your data in `viewWillAppear` method of parent controller

Comment: viewWillAppear seems to work perfectly.  It fires on initial start of view controller and also on any subsequent times logic comes back to parent controller from a second view.  Just exactly what I wanted.  Thanks